# APC Power Controllers Inaccessible After Brief Power Loss

Tags: electrical-power, rack, apc

It seems like every time there is a brief power outage in our environment (1-2 second blip). There are generally a handful of APC power controllers that become inaccessible through network. The workaround is to unplug the device, wait a few seconds and plug it back in. Anyone have any ideas why this would happen and why the network card or APC itself would fail to boot entirely after a brief power loss?

We've asked APC about this multiple times and have not received any helpful responses.

Additionally we have seen similar behavior on WTI controllers as well. Maybe this is a common occurrence? If it is, then I hope someone else has experienced this and knows what the root cause is.

It does seem pretty ridiculous that the point of a power controller, which is to remotely manage the state of outlets becomes unable to do it's job when it's seemingly most important to do so.

Comment: Depends on the cause of your power outage, doesn't it?

Comment: What kinds of power outages can there be? Yea it's a problem that we don't know the cause. But I can at least give you some behavior. The outages most frequently occur in the summer. They only last for a second or so. Almost like a brownout.

Comment: Is there a UPS involved?

Comment: Totally inaccessible? Not even ping?   Could it be an issue with the switch the controller is plugged into? What are the settings at both ends for auto-negotiation etc?

Comment: Totally inaccessible, no ping no nothing. The ports are 100mbps we've tried auto and just setting them to full 100mbps both dont seem to help. It almost seems like the control module or NIC inside the APC is not booting as i dont get any feedback on the lights where its normally supposed to tell you amperage.